# Ungroup a custom quantum gate in QASM 2.0

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate

Is there any API provided by Qiskit to ungroup a custom quantum gate into its component quantum gate.

If there is no API, please let me know how to ungroup the custom gate after I made own quantum_circuit by using the `QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file()`

Comment: Would [decompse](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.decompose.html) achieve what you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is your intention exactly, so here are several options:

1. [IBM Quantum Composer](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/docs/iqx/) is a sort of API for composing quantum circuits - You can easily enter QASM code there and the corresponding circuit will be loaded. Then you can modify the circuit freely.
2. If you wish to decompose a generalized unitary operation to some set of qunatum gates - Then there are some different ways to do that. The most common methods are [`decompose()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.decompose.html) and [`transpile()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html). The `transpile` method allows many degrees of freedom - one can choose a set of target basis gates for the circuit to be transpiled to, or alternatively it is possible to set a transpile operation compatible with a specific hardware ("backend"), and lots of other options are available - Take a look at the documentation.
3. If you are looking for a method to convert a gate/circuit to QASM code - Then the [`QuantumCircuit.qasm()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.qasm.html) method does this job.

Comment: ```decompose()``` method is wokred. Thank you